# Ajax centric Open source

Tags: ajax

Do we have some thing like an wrapper for ajax. If so can some name the best one.

Comment: Please add more details - 1) What are you trying to do? Different libraries are better at different things. 2) Is there a preference for Javascript library size, or doesn't it matter? 3) What browsers are you targeting, if any?

Comment: If there were a "best one", then we'd only have 1, since everyone would use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense, but I think what you're looking for is a javascript framework. Popular choices are [jquery](http://jquery.com/) or [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)